# Parsing a JSON object in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55f13d34258687e0bb9e4385"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple1@gmail.com","last_login":"11:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user1","password":"qwerty123"}
{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55ef49dd5d610eab18719deb"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple2@gmail.com","last_login":"12:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user2","password":"qwerty123"}
{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55f0173bb3322bf560724fd1"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple3@gmail.com","last_login":"10:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user3","password":"qwerty123"}
```

Hello, I working in nodeJS file and there I have a collection of JSON objects and I would like to make a search through it. For each user from this list I need to compare the field "last_login" .
I am new to nodeJS can someone help? Thank you!

This is what i have tried:

```
User.find({}, {last_login: }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to display last logins.' });
    }
    docs.forEach(function(doc, index) {
      res.json({success: true, message: 'time of last login', last_login: doc.last_login});
    })
    //res.json(users);
  });
});
```

Where last_login is a field in the User object and basically I need to iterate over all users in the db and extract only the last_login and display in in the response.I don’t know what value to put in the find() inside the curly braces
this is the part where I am stuck

I’ve slightly changed the function and it returns a JSON object containing the info about one user that is matched with the search query. The problem is, the console displays the result, as a whole object, although I want to get only a specific key value pair and namely last_login: value

```
function searchByUserName(name_surname) {
    return list.filter(function(user) {
        return user.name_surname === name_surname;
    });
}
var a = searchByUserName('user1');
for (last_login in a ) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(last_login)) {
    console.log("last_login" + "=" + JSON.stringify(a[last_login]))
  }
}
```

Can you tell me please, what change to make in order to get only the last_login key
here is a sample result from the console.log() that I receive:

```
last_login={"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55f13d34258687e0bb9e4385"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple1@gmail.com","last_login":"11:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user1","password":"qwerty123"}
```

although I want `last_login = “last_login”: 11:25:24 AM`

Comment: What have to tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: so what do you expect as result?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: have you got the answer ?

Comment: not yet ( @Mritunjay

Comment: can you try bellow `console.log("last_login" + "=" + a['last_login'])`.. let me know

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's an array of objects like bellow.

```
var users = [{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55f13d34258687e0bb9e4385"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple1@gmail.com","last_login":"11:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user1","password":"qwerty123"},
{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55ef49dd5d610eab18719deb"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple2@gmail.com","last_login":"12:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user2","password":"qwerty123"},
{"__v":0,"_id":{"$oid":"55f0173bb3322bf560724fd1"},"admin":true,"email":"emaple3@gmail.com","last_login":"10:25:24 AM","name_surname":"user3","password":"qwerty123"}];
```

you can create a function like bellow

```
function searchByLastLogin(last_login) {
    return users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.last_login === last_login;
    });
}

console.log(searchByLastLogin("12:25:24 AM"));
console.log(searchByLastLogin("10:25:24 AM"));
console.log(searchByLastLogin("11:25:24 AM"));
```

It will retrun a array of `users` whose `last_login` will match to given parameter `last_login`.

## Update

What I understood from your comment bellow, you want last logins of every user.

For that you can do something like bellow

```
var last_logins = users.map(function(user){
    return user.last_login;
});

console.log(last_logins); //prints [ '11:25:24 AM', '12:25:24 AM', '10:25:24 AM' ]
```

## References

[*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) | [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have an additional, possibly silly question: I see you named the array of the users in the db “users”, but the problem is I don’t know how is the implicit name of the db array in the MongoDB. I think “User” is the name of the collection but I am not sure how to iterate through every item (JSON object) in the collection. Because what I want is to get a list of all the last logins (last_login) for every user.

Comment: @Chris I've just taken your data in a variable, I'm not getting what `db` you are reffering to.

Comment: I’ve slightly changed the function and it returns a JSON object containing the info about one user that is matched with the search query. The problem is, the console displays the result, as a whole object, although I want to get only a specific key value pair and namely last_login: value

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t know what value to put in the find() inside the curly braces this is the part where I am stuck

If I understand correctly, you only want to get the `last_login`  field for the user model, and that's what you're struggling with ?

According to the documentation, this should work if you only want to get that field :

```
User.find({}, {last_login:1, _id:0})
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works but it only displays the field for the first user in the db. However, I need to iterate through all the users in the db and for each to perform this task. Can you give me a proper way to iterate through all the db?